# Does anyone see what is causing a segmentation fault in this BST code?

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

class tree
{
    private:

    public:
        struct leaf
        {
            int data;
            leaf *l;
            leaf *r;
        };
        struct leaf *p;

        tree();
        ~tree();
        void destruct(leaf *q);
        tree(tree& a);
        void findparent(int n,int &found,leaf* &parent);
        void findfordel(int n,int &found,leaf *&parent,leaf* &x);
        void add(int n);
        void transverse();
        void in(leaf *q);
        void pre(leaf *q);
        void post(leaf *q);
        void del(int n);
        leaf*  createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len);

};

tree::tree()
{
    p=NULL;
}

tree::~tree()
{
    destruct(p);
}

void tree::destruct(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        destruct(q->l);
        del(q->data);
        destruct(q->r);
    }
}
void tree::findparent(int n,int &found,leaf *&parent)
{
    leaf *q;
    found=NO;
    parent=NULL;

    if(p==NULL)
        return;

    q=p;
    while(q!=NULL)
    {
        if(q->data==n)
        {
            found=YES;
            return;
        }
        if(q->data>n)
        {
            parent=q;
            q=q->l;
        }
        else
        {
            parent=q;
            q=q->r;
        }
    }
}

void tree::add(int n)
{
    int found;
    leaf *t,*parent;
    findparent(n,found,parent);
    if(found==YES)
        cout<<"\nSuch a Node Exists";
    else
    {
        t=new leaf;
        t->data=n;
        t->l=NULL;
        t->r=NULL;

        if(parent==NULL)
            p=t;
        else
            parent->data > n ? parent->l=t : parent->r=t;
    }
}

void tree::transverse()
{
    int c;
    cout<<"\n1.InOrder\n2.Preorder\n3.Postorder\nChoice: ";
    cin>>c;
    switch(c)
    {
        case 1:
            in(p);
            break;

        case 2:
            pre(p);
            break;

        case 3:
            post(p);
            break;
    }
}

void tree::in(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        in(q->l);
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
        in(q->r);
    }

}

void tree::pre(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
        pre(q->l);
        pre(q->r);
    }

}

void tree::post(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        post(q->l);
        post(q->r);
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
    }

}

void tree::findfordel(int n,int &found,leaf *&parent,leaf *&x)
{
    leaf *q;
    found=0;
    parent=NULL;
    if(p==NULL)
        return;

    q=p;
    while(q!=NULL)
    {
        if(q->data==n)
        {
            found=1;
            x=q;
            return;
        }
        if(q->data>n)
        {
            parent=q;
            q=q->l;
        }
        else
        {
            parent=q;
            q=q->r;
        }
    }
}

void tree::del(int num)
{
    leaf *parent,*x,*xsucc;
    int found;

    // If EMPTY TREE
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\nTree is Empty";
        return;
    }
    parent=x=NULL;
    findfordel(num,found,parent,x);
    if(found==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nNode to be deleted NOT FOUND";
        return;
    }

    // If the node to be deleted has 2 leaves
    if(x->l != NULL && x->r != NULL)
    {
        parent=x;
        xsucc=x->r;

        while(xsucc->l != NULL)
        {
            parent=xsucc;
            xsucc=xsucc->l;
        }
        x->data=xsucc->data;
        x=xsucc;
    }

    // if the node to be deleted has no child
    if(x->l == NULL && x->r == NULL)
    {
        if(parent->r == x)
            parent->r=NULL;
        else
            parent->l=NULL;

        delete x;
        return;
    }

    // if node has only right leaf
    if(x->l == NULL && x->r != NULL )
    {
        if(parent->l == x)
            parent->l=x->r;
        else
            parent->r=x->r;

        delete x;
        return;
    }

    // if node to be deleted has only left child
    if(x->l != NULL && x->r == NULL)
    {
        if(parent->l == x)
            parent->l=x->l;
        else
            parent->r=x->l;

        delete x;
        return;
    }
}


tree::leaf* tree::createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len)
{
    int i;
    tree::leaf *bst = new tree::leaf;
//  tree bst;
    if(len < 0)
        bst = NULL;
        return bst;

    bst->data = *preOrder;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(*(inOrder + i) == *preOrder)
        break;
    bst->l = createBST(preOrder + 1, inOrder, i);
    bst->r = createBST(preOrder + i +1, inOrder + i + 1, len-i-1);
    return bst;

}

int main()
{
/*  tree t;
    int data[]={32,16,34,1,87,13,7,18,14,19,23,24,41,5,53};
    for (int iter=0; iter<15; iter++)
    {
        t.add(data[iter]);
    }
    t.transverse();
    t.del(16);
    t.transverse();
    t.del(41);
    t.tranverse();
*/  

    tree bst;
    int pre_data[] = {20,8,4,12,10,14,22};
    int in_data[] = {4,8,10,12,14,20,22};
    bst.p = bst.createBST(pre_data, in_data, 7);
    bst.transverse();

    return 0;
}
```

***************Edited:***************************

Compile free error. But I got segmentation fault after run.

Run it under gcc.

Comment: You are not collecting what `tree::createBST(...)` returns in `main()`. So, why are you returning any way.

Comment: The restriction on asking two questions in less than 20 minutes is there because the people who designed Stack Overflow think you should not be asking two questions in less than 20 minutes. Please consider the possibility that they had good reasons, rather than looking for ways to subvert the system.

Comment: your `tree::createBST` is a mess, and it causes undefined behavior because you return a reference to a local variable.

Comment: I changed my code in main. and moved leaf struct to public block. Still seg fault

Comment: This code looks awfully familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5366359/78845

Comment: @ Johnsyweb yes, that is me. I cannot ask 2 ques in 20 mins, so I change to another acct. thanks. and that post answer my one question. This is different one. So I ask a new here. that's why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weird error in binary search tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372084/weird-error-in-binary-search-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tree::leaf* tree::createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len)
{
    int i;
    tree::leaf *bst = new tree::leaf;
    //  tree bst;
    if(len < 0)
        bst = NULL;
    return bst;  // This doesn't come under `if` statement. Nothing gets executed 
                 // after this statement. So, returning a leaf whose members are 
                 // not initialized at all.

    // ....

}
```

Now you are collecting it `main()` -

```
bst.p = bst.createBST(pre_data, in_data, 7);
```

The members of `bst.p`( i.e., l,r, data ), are not assigned any values. But you are requesting for any of those on call to `in(..), pre(..), post(..)` and hence the *segmentation fault*.

Comment: thanks, This is a problem. I have changed it, but still seg fault.

Comment: @Josh - Learn to use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As *Mahesh*'s comment hints, your `createBST` method doesn't actually modify the `tree` object you call it on. So your tree starts off empty; it isn't made nonempty by calling `createBST`; your traversal of the tree then does nothing because you're traversing an empty tree.