# Weird error in binary search tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

class tree
{
    private:

    public:
        struct leaf
        {
            int data;
            leaf *l;
            leaf *r;
        };
        struct leaf *p;
        tree();
        ~tree();
        void destruct(leaf *q);
        tree(tree& a);
        void add(int n);
        void transverse();
        void in(leaf *q);
        void pre(leaf *q);
        void post(leaf *q);
        leaf*  createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len);     
};      
tree::tree()
{
    p=NULL;
}
tree::~tree()
{
    destruct(p);
}
void tree::destruct(leaf *q)
{

}

void tree::transverse()
{
    int c;
    cout<<"\n1.InOrder\n2.Preorder\n3.Postorder\nChoice: ";
    cin>>c;
    switch(c)
    {
        case 1:
            in(p);
            break;

        case 2:
            pre(p);
            break;

        case 3:
            post(p);
            break;
    }
}
void tree::in(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        in(q->l);
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
        in(q->r);
    }

}
void tree::pre(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
        pre(q->l);
        pre(q->r);
    }

}
void tree::post(leaf *q)
{
    if(q!=NULL)
    {
        post(q->l);
        post(q->r);
        cout<<"\t"<<q->data<<endl;
    }

}



tree::leaf* tree::createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len)
{
    int i;
    tree::leaf *bst = new tree::leaf;
//  tree bst;
//  if(len < 0)
//      {//bst = NULL;
//      return bst;}

    bst->data = *preOrder;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if(*(inOrder + i) == *preOrder)
        break;
    if(i>=0)    
        bst->l = createBST(preOrder + 1, inOrder, i);
    if((len-i-1) >=0)
        bst->r = createBST(preOrder + i +1, inOrder + i + 1, len-i-1);
    return bst;

}

int main()
{


    tree bst;
    int pre_data[] = {20,8,4,12,10,14,22};
    int in_data[] = {4,8,10,12,14,20,22};
    bst.p = bst.createBST(pre_data, in_data, 7);
    bst.transverse();

    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is in function

```
  tree::leaf* tree::createBST(int *preOrder, int* inOrder, int len)
```

Note: I've posted two questions about this. Because I modified my code a lot I started a fresh post.

Comment: In English, 'transverse' means 'across' or 'cross-wise'; you probably should be using 'bst.traverse()`.

Comment: @sth , compile time segmentation faults

Comment: @user: Which compiler? And how do you know that the problem is in the function you mentioned?

Comment: You should state what problem you are trying to solve, what your intended solution is and what seems to be wrong in your code. If you have a compiler error or the program has unexpected results, unwanted behavior...

Comment: Compiles just fine for me, except for an undefined function `del()`.

Comment: yeah. I deleted not relevant code. Compile fine for me. But run time segmentation fault happen.

Comment: -1 It's the third question about the same problem.

Comment: Compile-time seg fault? "compiles just fine, except for ..."? I suspect trolling...

Comment: I have voted to close as *not a real question*. The reason is that you are not asking anything, just providing some code and a vague statement that it has a *weird* problem (not even state whether it is compile/link/run-time). You did not provide any information on what you are trying to solve, and what your approach (algorithm) is. I have noticed that you have already accepted an answer, so this *vote to close* does not have any effect at all for you. But note that keeping on posting bad answers will end up with them being deleted, and in many cases before anyone is able to help.

Comment: @David, agreed. Voting to close as 'not a real question.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is that you have no terminating condition for your recursion.  Consider the case where `len == 0`, you will execute this line of code:

```
bst->l = createBST(preOrder + 1, inOrder, i);
```

This will pass in a length of 0 and the same thing will happen again.  This is infinite recursion, and will cause a segmentation fault.

I think your problem is solved by adding this to beginning of `createBST`:

```
if(len == 0)
    return NULL;
```

Comment: thank you JaredC. Exactly. You saved my time. Thank u. Problem solved.